# Unknown column 'this_.id' in 'field list' when fetching With Hibernate and MySql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am begginer in Hibernate and i have a table named `suffrages1` with no relations to the rest of the database.

The table has an autoincrement identifier field named `Suffrages_id`.

In the corresponding entity, i am declaring the field as follows :

```
@Entity(name = "suffrages1")  
 public class Suffrage1 implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@JoinColumn(name = "Suffrages_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
```

The insertion is fine but when i try to fetch i get this error :`Unknown column 'this_.id' in 'field list'`

 All similar issues i found were about problems with relationships between tables or about correct column names for mapping but as i said this table has no relationship with other table and i think i have the correct names e,g i know that my Java variable in the class is named `id` but is annotated with `@JoinColumn` to correspond to the Mysql column. So where did  `'this_.id'` come from ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i was using `@JoinColumn` instead of `@Column` to define the `id` field.